# How Angular's Scope is different from model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How Angular's Scope is different from model?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "myname";
});
```

Name is present in scope or model?

Comment: You should read about MVC architecture - Model View Controller. You *bind* your data with the Model, which can *update* the View, by *manipulating* such data in the Controller. Scope variables are objects that are bound to the application model.